# Bootstrap jquery plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to learn about Bootstrap. I used to use jquery and I saw you can choose which jquery plugins should be included, for instance: Carousel functionality, Dropdowns, Modals, Togglable tabs, so on.

My question is if I want to include another jquery plugin, let's say http://jqueryvalidation.org/ to validate forms, is it possible? or Do I have to use only the plugins listed here http://getbootstrap.com/customize/?id=7634993#plugins

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap.js is dependent on jQuery, and is essentially a library of jQuery plugins for various page components. Similar in regard to jQueryUI being a library of plugins also.

The javascript components within bootstrap can be self initialized on page load by using `data-` attributes specified for each component, or using same initialization concept as the majority of jQuery plugins, creating a configuration object argument of the plugin method and assigning it to a selector.

Using the `data-` attributes, on page load, bootsrap.js will look for all these in the page so it can create configuration objects used to do the atomatic initialization.

Pseudo HTML

```
<div data-widgetName data-option_1="123" data-option_2="left">
```

Simplified jQuery parsing of `data-` in order to intialize each componnent type plugin ( done transparently by bootstrap.js)

```
$('[data-widgetName]').each(function(){
    /* create config for this particular widget*/
    var widgetConfig={
         option_1: $(this).data('option_1'),
         option_2: $(this).data('option_2')
    }
     /* iniitalize this widget type plugin*/
    $(this).bootstrap_widgetName( widgetConfig)
});
```

Now visualize this being done for all the various component types within the library. As you can see, behind the scenes bootsrap is basically doing what you do when you manually code initialization of a plugin.

You don't have to set the `data-` attributes either and are free to use your own code to initialize them by passing in the proper config object.

```
$('a.popoverClass').popover({ /* options*/});
```

In summary,
Using bootsrap.js doesn't limit you using other plugins, other than potentially attempting to conflict with bootstrap modules whose DOM structure may have been changed, or interfering with events bound to elements that bootstrap plugins interact with.